# How is an A320 on the ground kept cool inside if the APU fails?

Tags: airbus-a320, apu

What happens to the air conditioner when the APU is not available due to damage or it just fails?

Also adding that the airport does not have an air conditioning unit. Since it is above average sea level, what procedures should be performed?

Comment: Depending on turn around, they may just keep one engine running, especially not having bleed air for a restart.

Comment: Can one or more packs run with ground source?

Answer (score 3):

They can leave one engine running to take the place of the APU. If that's not possible for whatever reason, the interior just gets warm.

Comment: And they cannot start the engines again without an external huffer, which probably means they might try and swap the plane in case they can't leave the engine running.